# Override ToString for specified property

Tags: c#, properties, overriding, tostring

I have this class

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTimeOffset MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

How can I override the ToString method only for the MyDate property?
So, when I call

```
obj.MyDate.ToString()
```

I will have my own implementation.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this property-wise since the `ToString()` belongs to the type, inherited from `object`.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTimeOffset` is a structure. There is no way to override `ToString` method as structure cannot be inherited.

Your option is to use one of the overload to format string representation([DateTimeOffset.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTimeOffset_ToString_System_String_)).

You can either use [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to get required format.

Comment: An additional option, if you preferred, would to add an additional readonly `MyDateString` property to your class whereby the `get` method performed the formatting you required. You would have to weigh the "cost" of an additional property against potential, repeated formatting calls.